# find inverse of Interaction between object arrays typescript

Tags: json, angular, typescript

I have an agent object like this

```
agentObj = {
    "agentId": "saqib",
    "attributes": [
        {
            "name": "Marketing",
            "type": "Boolean",
        },
        {
            "name": "English",
            "type": "Proficiency",
        },
   ],

}
```

and attributes array like this

```
attributesObj =  [
{
    "name": "Marketing",
    "type": "Proficient",
},
{
    "name": "English",
    "type": "Boolean",
},
{
    "name": "D",
    "type": "Proficient",
}]
```

how to get the attributes from attributesObj which are not present in the attributes[] array of agentObj.

Comment: your `agentObj` is an array or you did a typo ?

Comment: What you tried?

Comment: agentobj is object which contains the attributes array, i first tried to get the attributes array from agentObj and then compare it with attributesObj to find the unmatched values, i didn't get any method to get array from the object

Answer (score 0):

Iterate through the attributesObj and use

agentObj.attributes.find(a => a.name === b.name)

to check if the element is present.
If the agentObj is an array of objects you just need to iterate through it as well and call .find on each elements attributes property.